# How to add style to after class P Tag

Tags: css

need to add display: inline;  style for First P tag.

```html
<div class="showques">
  <div class="lab_tre">A</div> &nbsp;
  <p> Text1 </p>
  <p>Text 2 para </p>
</div>
```

How can do this

Comment: `.lab_tre + p { }` [Adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target the first `p` type element that is a child (but not grandchild) of `.showques` class using the `first-of-type` pseudo class selector.

However, since items before and after the first `p` element has `display: block;` by default, they would still show in different lines.

```css
.showques > p:first-of-type {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="showques">
  <div class="lab_tre">A</div>
  <p> Text1 </p>
  <p>Text 2 para </p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS,

`p { display: inline }` will display all P tags in-line.

`.showques p { display: inline }` will alter only the P tags inside your 'showques' box

Comment: `.lab-tre` is not a parent, but sibling of `p` elements.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right. This is what happens when trying to answer questions within half an hour of waking up. I've edited the answer. Thanks Samet.